# returning true or false from a function in angular 6

Tags: angular

I'd like to call a function from within another function. My code looks like this:
this is my parent-function:

```
} else {
    if(this.checkIfCountyExists(data.convertedAddress[0].county)) {
       console.log('true');
    } else {
       console.log('false');
    }
}
```

this is my child-function which gets called within parent-function:

```
checkIfCountyExists(county: String) {
    this.localisationService.checkCounty(county).subscribe(data => {
        if(data.success) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

my service holds an interface for the returned data which looks like this:

```
interface data {
  success: Boolean,
  convertedAddress: any
}
```

But the function never gets called correctly, because it returns `everytime`. So how can i create a function which correctly returns true and false?

VisualStudio says

> an expression of type void cannot be tested for truthiness

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your method is asynchronous thus it does not wait at your if statement and continues to execute. That is why you are always jumping to else condition.

Convert your `checkIfCountyExists` method to Observable

```
checkIfCountyExists(county: String) {
    return this.localisationService.checkCounty(county).map(data => {
        if(data.success) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

then

```
this.checkIfCountyExists(data.convertedAddress[0].county).Subscribe(res => {
       if(res) {
           console.log('true');
       } else {
           console.log('false');
       }
});
```

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you, please consider to mark it as answer :) Regards

Comment: this is only possible, when the question is 20 minutes old :). But i did it now, thank you again!